# Obj-C - How to add a menu bar on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, overlay

I would like to create a menu bar on a map like in the bottom of the image.
It has a search bar on the top and three buttons on the bottom.
How can I join the buttons with the searchbar like in the image?
Thankssss.

[image]

SOLUTION:

I followed the ezatu丶 code with some changes:

- `UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath
                            bezierPathWithRoundedRect:searchBar.bounds
                            byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                            cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(6, 6)
                            ];

  CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

  maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

  searchBar.layer.mask = maskLayer;

  [toolView addSubview:searchBar];` to create the rounded corner and the shadow, the same code to the button into the for cycle.
- Lightgray background of the view.
- UITextfield with magnifier image with this code: `UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 40)];
  myTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
  myTextField.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"asdf"]];
  myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` instead of the search bar.

Thanks to ezatu丶

Comment: set the menu bar view top , below it set the map view.

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a customize view add to self.view and bringTop the view.

here is the sample code :

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height

CGFloat margin = 10;
CGFloat viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - 2 * margin;
CGFloat viewHeight = 82;

UIView *toolView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, SCREEN_HEIGHT - viewHeight - margin, viewWidth, viewHeight)];
toolView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 40)];
[toolView addSubview:searchBar];

CGFloat btnWidth = (viewWidth - 4) / 3;
CGFloat btnHeight = 40;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld btn", i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [toolView addSubview:btn];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(i *(btnWidth + 1), 42, btnWidth, btnHeight);
}

[self.view addSubview:toolView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:toolView];
```

[image]

Comment: i don't make the style about the searchbar and buttons , you can do what you want .

Comment: otherwise, you can use the UITextField to replace the UISearchBar, because use the UITextField is more easily achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the view on map view controller where you add these all button and search bar. and set the search bar style to minimum from storyboard.

Comment: I know how overlay the view on the map but not how to join the buttons and the bar like in the image.

Comment: You means these black line between buttons and searchbar?